# Variance for random variable X

Tags: probability

I have a probability distribution like so,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/(2x) & x\geq 2\\
11/40 & x=1
\end{cases}$$

I know the mean is $2.775$ so in order to find the variance for $X$, I use

$$E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^6 (x - 2.775)^2 f(x)$$

I have tried subbing in all the values and cannot get any value other then $2.1567$
and the answer should be $2.5743$.

Any clues about where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hopefully the fixes I made to your formatting are ok.

Comment: Thank you :) It's what I was trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $x \ge 2$ means $x = 2,3,4,5,6$?

Yes, $$\sum_{x=1}^6 (x-2.775)^2 f(x) = 2.574375$$
I suspect you've made an arithmetic error.  Without seeing your actual calculations, it's impossible to tell where that occurred.

Comment: Thank you, I went back and looked over it again :)